# Craig Interpolation for first order sentence

Tags: first-order-logic

I understand how to produce an interpolant for propositional logic, but i have trouble to understand how to produce an interpolant for a first order sentence.
I'm using the textbook First-Order logic and automated theorem proving by Melvin Fitting, 2nd edition.

I want to produce an interpolant for the following first-order sentence:
$[(\forall x) (P(x) \implies \lnot Q(x)) \land P(c)] \implies \lnot Q(c)$

As for the propositional case i would produce a closed tableau, my tableau looks like this
[image: tableau]

Using the rules for propositional logic my interpolant would by $(\forall x) [x/c] \lor (\forall x) [x/c]$ but i don't think that this is right. Can someone explain me how to produce an interpolant for this sentence? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you have to add the predicate symbols...

Comment: Oh, so if i think about it, i would say the interpolant is $\lnot P(c) \lor \lnot Q(c)$ isnt it?